# where is the error in my ajax script that return NoneType to the views.py

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

i have  ajax script that send selected option from a dropdown list to the django function using **GET method**, i am sending the data in **json format**

the problem once i select an option from the dropdown list it display the below error:

> File "C:\Users\LT
>   GM\Desktop\test2ForImportExport\test2\testpro\views.py", line 30, in
>   getdetails
>       answer = str(country_name[1:-1]) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

## home2.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
                <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
             $('select#selectcountries').change(function () {
                 var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
                 var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
                 var country_name   = optionSelected.text();


                 data = {'cnt' : country_name };
                 alert(country_name);
                 $.ajax({
                     type:"GET",
                     url:'/getdetails',
                     data:JSON.stringify(data),
                     success:function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                        $("#selectcities option").remove();
                        for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            $("#selectcities").append('<option>'+ result[i].name +'</option>');
                        };
                      },
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select name="selectcountries" id="selectcountries">
        {% for item in countries %}
            <option val="{{ item.name }}"> {{ item.name }} </option>    
        {% endfor %}
        </select>   


        <select name ="selectcities" id="selectcities">


        </select>       

        <select name ="selectroads" id="selectroads">


        </select>



    </body>
</html>
```

## views.py

```
def home2(request):
    countries = country.objects.all()
    print(countries)
    return render(request, 'home2.html',{'countries': countries})



def getdetails(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
        country_name = request.GET.get('cnt', None) 
        print ("ajax country_name ", country_name)

        result_set = []
        all_cities = []

        answer = str(country_name[1:-1])
        print('answer = ' ,answer)
        selected_country = country.objects.get(name=answer)
        print ("selected country name ", selected_country)

        all_cities = selected_country.city_set.all()
        for city in all_cities:
            print ("city name", city.name)
            result_set.append({'name': city.name})

        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result_set),content_type='application/json')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You've sent your data as JSON, not as normal query data, so it isn't present in `request.GET['cnt']`.

The easiest thing to do is to remove that `JSON.stringify` call from the JS, so the parameter to the ajax call would just be `data: data`.

Comment: ok  this was the problem but know i have another problem  after it display the result in console  the system stop

Comment: i mean in the console the displayed result is [ ] mean *its empty*